# Why is an old question a duplicate of a new one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

The question that was asked a year ago:

> [Why does the use of Random with a hardcoded seed always produce the same results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044570/why-does-the-use-of-random-with-a-hardcoded-seed-always-produce-the-same-results)

is closed as a duplicate of the one that was asked 11 days ago:

> [Why does this code print “hello world”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-print-hello-world)

Did I miss something? (I am sorry if this was asked before. If so, let me know in the comments)

Comment: Well. Wouldn't you say the new one has a definite better canonical feel to it? More answers, more details, more views...

Comment: Most likely because the new one has far more answers and votes than the old one, making it to some extent more canonical. Age doesn't really always matter. In this case closure is a signpost.

Comment: I accidentally removed my comment: I was trying to search for a related question but couldn't find one as I type mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When closing questions as duplicates, the idea is to link to the canonical question/answer - the best possible post. Post ages don't come into it.

The new question and its answers have a much larger number of upvotes, there are more answers (some of which are better than the single answer on the old question).

Comment: Does the search hides heavily downvoted questions? I can't seem to search for one as I type mine (I kept looking for the possible related questions on the right and in the [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=old+question+duplicate+new)).

Comment: @Antony - Not sure about that. I don't think it does - the question search on the ask page is not great at the moment - it only searches for titles.